# Whats the difference between -sS and -PS in nmap?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nmap, port-scanning

I was learning how to use nmap and i have gone through many documentations and tutorials but no where iam getting perfect information about what is the use of -sS and -PS. In general what is the differences between all -s 's and -P 's? Both are for scanning right?

```
sudo nmap -sS 192.168.0.50
sudo nmap -PS 192.168.0.50
```

Whats the difference between both of them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is well described in [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap).

Before doing port scan, nmap will ping the host to check if it's online. `-P` options are used to select different ping methods. When `-PS` is selected, nmap will check if hosts are online by sending single SYN packet. `-Pn` will skip this phase and jump right to port scan.

`-s*` options select the method of detecting open ports (for hosts which were determined to be online). With `-sS` this will be done by sending single `SYN` packet to each port.

It makes sense to combine those options together: `nmap -sS -PS 192.168.0.50` will cause nmap to use `SYN` packets both for ping and to discover open ports.

Answer (score 3):

http://nmap.org/book/man-briefoptions.html

One is for host discovery, the other is for scanning techniques (in case a firewall/host blocks the default techniques or you have a reason to use other than defaults)

-PS: TCP SYN/ACK, UDP or SCTP discover to given ports

-sS: TCP SYN/Connect scans

As a sidenote - you don't *need* any cmd line flags to do a scan, just `nmap <your_host>` will work.

I usually use the `-A` flag which does OS detection, version detection, script scanning, and traceroute.

When a host doesn't respond but I know it's online, I add the `-Pn` flag which skips the initial host discovery part and starts scanning services, etc.

Like:
`nmap -A 8.8.8.8`
or
`nmap -Pn -A 8.8.8.8`

Comment: So -PS will send a TCP SYN packet to find the host and -sS will send TCP SYN packets to scan ports on the given ip address. Am i right @SnakeDoc ?

Comment: @RevanthKumar Yes. One is for simply seeing if the host responds (is online) in the event ICMP has been disabled, etc, the other is trying to get a port/service to respond.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Default host discovery probe is not only ICMP. It is the equivalent of: `-PE -PS443 -PA80 -PP`